# Свой столбец в Cgridview?

Tags: php, yii

Как добавить свой столбец в CGridView (предположим на основании ид строки ищет связанное поле в другой таблице)? 
Есть несколько таблиц. Связь многие-ко-многим. Предположим я хочу отобразить строку

анализ || элемент

а таблицы вида

*анализ* || *анализ_элемент(сводная таблица с ид анализа и элемента)* || *элемент*

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал так

```
    function num($id)
{
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $name = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('value')
        ->from('a_analiz_data')
        ->where("elem_id = 4
                and analiz_id = $id")
        ->queryScalar();
    return $name;
}

 array('header'=>'Паспорт','value'=> 'num($data->id)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' =>'width: 25px; text-align:center;'),
    ),
```